# TextBox name in one-to-one relationship model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have model with one-to-one relationship.
I can't pass it from View to Controller.
Model looks like this:

```
public class Product
{
    ...
    public Address Adress;
}
public class Address
{
    public string name { get; set;}
    ...
}
```

How should I name a textbox?

```
@Html.TextBox("name", Model.Address.name)
```

Comment: Should probably be like `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address.name)`

Comment: There are several ways to solve this such as by custom model binding,html helpers,etc. What name are you seeing right now? @user1477388 That will probably name the text box Address.Name

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult ActionMethod(YourModel model, FormCollection form)
            {
    string storeControlValue = form["controlname"];
return ......
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your View, use the following:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.name)
```

Or,

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address.name)
```

And, your Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Product product)
{
  // Some code...
}
```

Also, follow the standard naming conventions. Property names should start with a capital letter. So, use "Name" instead of "name".

Answer (score 0):

That was stupid error. I was missing {get; set} in Address. And TextBox should look like this:

```
@Html.TextBox("Address.name", Model.Address.name)
```

Thanks for all answers